# How does calling reader.Validate(MyReader{}) calls my custom Read method?

Tags: arrays, go, infinite-loop

https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/master/solutions/readers.go

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/reader"

type MyReader struct{}

func (r MyReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) { . //Q1) How is this method getting called?
//Q2) Its no where called in this source code
//Q3) What is the length of b ?
    for i := range b { //Q4) Why isn't throwing an infinite loop ?
        b[i] = 'A' 
    }
    return len(b), nil
}

func main() {
    reader.Validate(MyReader{})
}
```

Comment: You have multiple questions in your comments (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4); for StackOverflow purposes, you should work on breaking these up into individual questions. Doing so will help you focus on each part. tclass's answer is focused on Q1, with a bit of Q2. To answer Q4 for yourself (with too much detail! :-) ), see [the spec on `for` loops with `range` clauses](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements). The answer to Q3 requires reading the `validate.go` source (or testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it calls Read(b []byte) look at the source here https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/master/reader/validate.go#L17

Validate(io.Reader) expects an io.Reader, which only needs a Read([]byte) function to fullfill the interface. That is what you're doing, so Validate can call your reader.

Comment: "which only needs a Read([]byte) function" - But isn't the Read a method here?

Comment: yes and MyReader is an io.Reader because it (implizit) implements the io.Reader interface. Maybe you should read up on interfaces in go